# Securely add a user to group through FB.ui

Tags: facebook, security, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to use the Facebook Javascript SDK to add users to an app created group, and can't seem to see a solution that prevents malicious clients from inputting an arbitrary group id which is different from the group that I wish for them to join.

Thus far, my solution has been to use the 'game_group_join' method in an FB.ui dialog which looks like this:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'game_group_join',
    id: input.facebookGroupId,
    display: 'popup'
}, callback);
```

This works, but the Facebook group id is a parameter, and this is an issue since the dialog is produced on the client side.

In the Graph API's [Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_games) for version 2.0, it says:

> Apps can now show a client-side dialog as an alternative to adding users to a group on the server-side

which implies that there is (or used to be) a way to do this from the server.

How can I make this happen on the server side, or at least prevent a malicious client from having input about which group they are joining?

Comment: I don’t see how someone knowing the group id is an issue? The group admin has to confirm their join request in any case.